# How to collect q[t] from the following integration

Tags: numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis

As shown in the following program, the `q[t]` in `a` can be collected from the integration by defining the integration of `fe1[x]` as `Infe1[x]`, the same is true for `fe2[x]` in `b`. But for the equation `c`, how can I collect `q[t]` from it?

```
fe1 /: Integrate[fe1[x_], x_] := Infe1[x];
fe2 /: Integrate[fe2[x_], x_] := Infe2[x];

a = Integrate[fe1[x]*q[t], {x, 0, L1}]

b = Integrate[fe2[x]*q[t], {x, 0, L1}]   

c = Integrate[fe1[x]*fe2[x]*q[t], {x, 0, L1}]
```

Comment: @SunnySky, if you want to convert typeset math (`TraditionalForm`) input into `InputForm` you can use `Hold[ yourexpression ] // InputForm` and copy and paste the bit inside `Hold[]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a rule:

```
myrule = Integrate[Times[x_, q[t]], y_] :> q[t] Integrate[x, y]

c = Integrate[fe1[x]*fe2[x]*q[t], {x, 0, L1}] /. myrule

(*  ==>  Integrate[fe1[x]*fe2[x], {x, 0, L1}]*q[t]   *)
```

**Edit:**

For more generality, you could do

```
myrule2 = Integrate[Times[x_, c_], {y_, y1_, y2_}] /; FreeQ[c, y] :> c  Integrate[x, {y, y1, y2}];

Integrate[(1 + Exp[h[t]]^2) g[x, t] f[x] Exp[q[t]], {x, 0, L1}] //. myrule2

(* ==> E^q[t]*(1 + E^(2*h[t])) * Integrate[f[x]*g[x, t], {x, 0, L1}] *)
```

Note the use of `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`) rather than just `ReplaceAll` (`/.`).

Comment: your answer works well. thank you very much. Moreover, If the q[t] is substituted by q[t]*g[t]*r[t] or even a more complex functions that depend on "t", then how can I collect them from the integration without defining rules for each special functions?

Comment: @SunnySky please see if the update helps you

Comment: yes, your answer is very good. may be "//. myrule" should be replaced by "//. myrule2". Thank you very much.

Comment: Indeed. Corrected.